# Addint surface features to ellipsoid to visualize rotation

Tags: graphics

I am currently plotting an ellispoid using the following code

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}], m], 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}]
```

where `m` is an Euler matrix describing a rotation.

The problem I am running into is that when I rotate the ellipsoid around its central axis it is impossible to see in the Graphic as the body of the ellispoid is only colored with respect to the lighting. Is there a way to add some kind of surface gradient or mesh to a Graphics3D object to make this rotation visible?

I had tried using a form of RegionPlot3D but could not make it work with the Geometric Transform.

Comment: Add `m` definition what are you using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`First`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) to extract the graphics primitives of any graphics expression, including e.g. the output of [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html). Then you can simply apply your `GeometricTransformation` to that:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  Rotate[
   First@RegionPlot3D[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 2}], Mesh -> Full],
   θ,
   {0, 0, 1}
   ]
  ],
 {θ, 0, 2 π}
 ]
```

[image: Animation]